# DocumentBuilder parsing error with xml

Tags: java

I have a XML in String variable and I want to pass that value into the parse() of DocumentBuilder.

```
String xml = "<?xml version="1.0 ....>";
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

But, seems like the last line doesnt work as doc is null.

Is there anything wrong with this?  I am just trying take a xml value and convert it to Document.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How do you know that "doc is null"? As your post is written, `db` is the only thing that is null, so if it's you're real code then you're swallowing exceptions, and never get to the `parse()` call.

Comment: I did system out on the doc and it is null.

Comment: @parsifal - and that of course would be the real problem.

Comment: With the code as shown you'll get a null pointer exception.  Please show real code.

Comment: @Tony - show the *exact* code that you're using, and the *exact* output. Either you're swallowing an exception, or you're misinterpreting the output from `Node.toString()` (which is easy to misinterpet). At the present time, all  can tell you is "your code has a bug," because the parser won't return null, it will throw.

Comment: If your code executes your last line without exception then doc can't be null - I don't think it's possible for DocumentBuilder.parse to return null. It can throw an exception though, e.g. a  SAXException if your XML is invalid.

Comment: That's still not the *exact* code and output. If you can't be bothered to help us, why should we be bothered to help you?

Comment: It is pretty closed to the exact code except for a way that xml was generated.  As I thought that there was an error on the last line, I just found out that I traced the error incorrectly.  The error was occurring at some places else.  The error is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something nearer

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

You can trim this to:

```
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Note that normally you'd expect an XML File and it'd be:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(fullpathtofile));
```